# Yii2 - connection of login template

Tags: templates, authentication, yii2

I'm using basic Yii2 template. I downloaded login template from the Internet (there are .html and .css files). I'd like to connect it to the Yii2 framework to be shown this way - when I write the the address on Internet browser, this login template will be shown as first, after login of user will be shown the basic Yii2 template and after logout will be shown the login template again.
How can I do that and where and what should I to set? Where should I copy the two files of the login template?

Answer (score 0):

To edit login template, you need to edit view files.

Since you're using basic yii2 application, you can go to `/views/site/login.php` file to edit login page template and copy html source. But make sure that you follow yii2 framework guideline while editing.

To add your own css, you can replace it on `/web/css/site.css`.

Comment: I want only change the login page and after a user log in I want to show the basic template and after a user log off I want to show the login template.